# Free JavaScript toolbar menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, menu

What is the best solution for implementing JavaScript drop-down menu in the Asp.Net website? Is it better to use some plugin (jQuery for example) or some "Menu generator"?

Comment: Are you looking for a context (right-click) menu, or an OS-like menu bar? "Best" by what criteria?

Comment: I wrote TOOLBAR menu. Like [File][Edit][About] in OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) is a popular option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery dropdown menus

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dropmenu

Answer (score 0):

You can check Syncfusion JavaScript Dropdown Menu

https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-dropdown-menu

Syncfusion offers a free community license

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion